# Log value change if original value is empty or new value is empty PHP

Tags: php

I have an edit profile page with a couple of fields where the value is set from the database (if its not NULL). It looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group f-left p-t-2 p-x-1">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label for="nationality" class="input-group-addon">
            Nationaliteit
        </label>
        <?php returnInputForm('nationality', 'nationality', $userinfo->nationality, 'Nationaliteit', 'form-control'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group f-left p-t-2 p-x-1">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label for="phone" class="input-group-addon">
            Telefoon
        </label>
        <?php returnInputForm('phone', 'phone', $userinfo->phone, 'Telefoon / GSM', 'form-control'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my controller method I call a helper function I wrote like this:

```
$this->logmanager->createAdminEditVolunteerLog($userinfo, $userdata, $adminuserid, $userid);
```

the $userinfo is the complete row of the database when doing a select * from x where id = $userid
the $userdata is the $_POST data submitted from the form of the page he is on. 
Note that the $userdata will always contain less fields than the $userinfo.

The function I wrote in the helper class looks like this:

```
public function createAdminEditVolunteerLog($dbrow, $submitted, $adminuserid, $userid)
{
    if (!is_array($dbrow)) {
        $dbrow = (array) $dbrow;
    }
    if (!is_array($submitted)) {
        $submitted = (array) $submitted;
    }

    $difference = array_diff($dbrow, $submitted);

    //Create a LOG entry
    foreach ($difference as $key => $value) {
        $entity = new stdClass();
        $entity->admin_user_id = $adminuserid;
        $entity->user_id = $userid;
        $entity->field = $key;
        $entity->prev_value = $dbrow[$key];
        $entity->new_value = $value;
        $entity->edit_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $this->CI->logAdminEditVolunteers_model->add($entity);
    }
}
```

This works perfect if the value is CHANGED! Meaning, if there was a value already in there and it is modified to another value!

In the following 2 cases nothing is logged:
- original value in $dbrow is empty but in $submitted it is not
- there is a value in $dbrow but in $submitted it is made empty

How do I make sure the last 2 cases are logged as well?

EDIT: I executed the following test scenario: The user has a phone number filled in, so I removed the value in the phone number and changed the first name, and added a value in bank_account, which was empty beforehand. 
the $dbrow looks like this:

```
    D:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\libraries\managers\LogManager.php:71:
    array (size=46)
      'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'national_number' => null
      'first_name' => string 'Dennis123' (length=9)
      'phone' => string '123' (length=3)
      'bank_account' => string '' (length=0)
      'bic_code' => string '' (length=0)
  'address_line2' => string '123' (length=3)
  'volunteer_location' => string 'Gentbrugge' (length=10)
  'volunteer_location_lat' => null
  'volunteer_location_long' => null
  'volunteer_location_max_distance' => string '50' (length=2)
  'national_number' => null
```

and the $submitted looks like this:

```
D:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\libraries\managers\LogManager.php:72:
array (size=16)
  'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'first_name' => string 'Dennis12' (length=8)
  'phone' => string '' (length=0)
  'bank_account' => string '123' (length=3)
  'bic_code' => string '' (length=0)
```

The $difference arrays (after using array_diff($submitted, $dbrow);) looks like this:

```
D:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\libraries\managers\LogManager.php:73:
array (size=2)
  'first_name' => string 'Dennis12' (length=8)
  'modified_at' => string '2018-01-02 19:55:27' (length=19)
```

I want this $difference array to look like this (so the phone and bank_account are added because they are modified, but the bic_code is not for example):

```
array (size=4)
      'first_name' => string 'Dennis12' (length=8)
      'modified_at' => string '2018-01-02 19:55:27' (length=19)
      'phone' => string '' (length=0)
      'bank_account' => string '123' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea.  You can do this to both arrays, so you get a difference.

Compare the ideas to the other array and add blank ones.

That way, the keys match in the arrays, so the array difference function gets the differences.

```
if (!is_array($dbrow)) 
{
    $dbrow = (array) $dbrow;
}
elseif (is_array($submitted)) 
{
    $dbrow = array();
    foreach ($submitted as $key => $value) 
    {
        $dbrow($key) = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just changed again.

Comment: Hi John! I don't really understand your answer, what does this do? 
I modified my question a bit to make this more clear with example data

Comment: It'll create an array with blank data in it.  So, you'll put your fields in it that you want to compare.  I'll make a tweak.

Comment: But if my $dbrow is an array I will never be in that else clause? 
As well, I do not know beforehand which values will be in my $submitted array, this can contain everytime a random amount of fields from the $dbrow array

Comment: Right...that's why it's dynamic now

Comment: I have the assumption that if the row is found ..the keys will match... otherwise it populates a row with a bunch of blank keys

Comment: If I use your code in the example I explained in my post, the $difference variable is null

Comment: I had to put a fix in. elseif (is_array($submitted))